# Rebus Azure topic names cleanup

Tags: rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

Working with AzureServiceBus, and using the ITopicnameConvention and for some reason my topic names have some "cleanup" after the GetTopic() method.

They all end up in lowercase and '.' are replaced with '_'

Am I missing something? I'm using the namespace and other combination of things to create topic names and I want them to be something like

MyDomain.Events

and I'm getting

mydomain_events

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you posted this question somewhere else, too, but I can't find it....?

Comment: you also posted the question here: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/692#issuecomment-561663283 – please close this one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of
https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/692#issuecomment-561663283

Comment: @mookid you are right.

Comment: To leave here an answer too: before v7 Rebus AzureServiceBus cleans the names. Start using v7 and works. Also when registering the topic convention use: Decorate<> instead of register